# How to set OverlayIcon on Electron windows app build for release with Squirrel.Windows

Tags: electron

I have packed the entire sources into one .exe folder. The icon of the app is set but my problem is that it does not recognise (same icon in my case) for setting overlay. 
The code extracted from package.js to make build:

```
"pack": "build --dir",
"dist": "build --win --ia32"


 "build": {     
      "icon": "icon.ico"
  }
```

And in index.html when i receive an event and need to overlay the icon it goes out the door and throws error. Same icon i use to set for the app.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1200, height: 800, icon: `icon.ico`, title: title})
```

[image]

I don't understand where is that path coming from... I expected to be the path of the icon from the resources of the app. The same one used for setting app icon. Lost on ideas here...Please help.

Relevant part from index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    const remoteElectron = require('electron').remote;
    const BrowserWindow = remoteElectron.BrowserWindow;
    const electron = require("electron");

    var win = remoteElectron.getCurrentWindow();

    var eventNewmsg = window.document.createEvent('Event');
    eventNewmsg.initEvent('okmsg', false, false);
    window.document.addEventListener("okmsg", function(){
        win.setOverlayIcon(`icon.ico`, "");
    }, false);

    window.eventNewMsg = eventNewmsg;
    var eventNomsg = window.document.createEvent('Event');
    eventNomsg.initEvent('cancelmsg', false, false);
    window.document.addEventListener("cancelmsg", function(){
        win.setOverlayIcon(null, "")
    }, false);
    window.eventNoMsg = eventNomsg;
</script>
```

Comment: Please post the code where you call `setOverlayIcon`.

Comment: I set the overlay icon in the index.html file. On an event we made. window.document.addEventListener("newmsg", function(){
   win.setOverlayIcon(`icon.ico`, "Test Description");
  }, false);

Comment: Can you post your entire `index.html`?

Comment: I have updated the question. Guess only that part is relevant from index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to be explicit when specifying paths, so if your icon is in the same directory as `index.html` you should do the following:

```
const path = require('path');
win.setOverlayIcon(path.join(__dirname, 'icon.ico', ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm i set in a different way the icon, and works pretty fine for me.

I'll leave you how i set it. works in all places.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    transparent: false,
    frame: false,
    fullscreen: false,
    width: 800,
    height: 400,
    resizable: false,
    movable: false,
    show: false,
    icon: __dirname + '/styles/images/app.png'
});
```